# User input and parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, concatenation

My goal:

1. Ask user for input (i.e. "Please enter a category: '*user input*'")
2. Search for data via API using '*user input*' as the query param
3. Return results back to user

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id='showCD'></div><br>
<input type="button" onclick="previous()" value="<<">
<input type="button" onclick="next()" value=">>">

<script>
var i = 0, len;
displayCD(i);


function displayCD(i) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this, i);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://www.example.com/api/search/?query=engines&format=xml', true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
  len = x.length;
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
  "Title: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Url: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Embed code: " + 
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

function next() {
  if (i < len-1) {
    i++;
    displayCD(i);
  }
}

function previous() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
    displayCD(i);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This returns results and let's me scroll through them with the buttons all fine and dandy but I can't seem to figure out a way to replace the value of 'engines', which I have above as the query param, with the value of '*user input*'. I thought I could create a variable with document.getElementById for the users input and then create another variable using url.concat(str1, str2) with url = 'http://www.example.com/api/search/?query=', str1 = the variable contain the returned user input, and str2 = '&format=xml' but it's not quite working.

So in short, the ultimate goal is: replace where the 'engine' query param is with whatever the users input is.

I'm think I'm needing to use callbacks or async. I'm new at this and still learning.

Comment: Where is the user input coming from, I can't see any inputs in the code apart from your two buttons? You sound like you have the right idea otherwise. Take the `value` from whatever element holds the user input via `document.getElement...` inside `displayCD()` and insert it into the url string via backticks like `?query=${userInput}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

...

<span>Please enter a category:</span>
<input type="text" id="category">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search()"

<script>

    function search() {
        let query = document.getElementById('category').value;
        let url = `http://www.example.com/api/search/?query=${query}&format=xml`;
        ...
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
        xmphttp.send();
    }

</script>


</body>
```